# Updating a Project with A number of git Submodules

Tags: git

I am working on a project that currently has  ~20 submodules. All the submodules need to be updated. None of them point to a remote repository, but there is one for each one of them.

Now I was thinking, to cd in to each submodule, and do a

```
git add remote ...
git fetch
git rebase origin ... OR git reset --hard origin
```

After I do that 20 times, I should be able to switch back to my main project and try to run the tests, and some UAT tests.

Is this apporach OK? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Which will make sure that the submodules are at the commits that they are supposed to be in according to your repository

If you want to run arbitrary code on each submodule in your repository, you can use the `foreach` command like so:

```
git submodule foreach '`git rebase origin`'
```

Comment: I could, but I dont know what that does, and you are saying to do that after I add the remote repositories right?

Comment: It's all explained in the docs https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html